# ESP-wroom-32 output problem with WiFi scan on Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, ide, esp32, arduino-ide

I want to scan all avaible wi-fi with my ESP-WROOM-32 and display the results on the Arduino IDE, i can upload this code to the board without problem

```
#include "WiFi.h"

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected.
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("Setup done");
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Scan start");

    // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found.
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    Serial.println("Scan done");
    if (n == 0) {
        Serial.println("no networks found");
    } else {
        Serial.print(n);
        Serial.println(" networks found");
        Serial.println("Nr | SSID                             | RSSI | CH | Encryption");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
            Serial.printf("%2d",i + 1);
            Serial.print(" | ");
            Serial.printf("%-32.32s", WiFi.SSID(i).c_str());
            Serial.print(" | ");
            Serial.printf("%4d", WiFi.RSSI(i));
            Serial.print(" | ");
            Serial.printf("%2d", WiFi.channel(i));
            Serial.print(" | ");
            switch (WiFi.encryptionType(i))
            {
            case WIFI_AUTH_OPEN:
                Serial.print("open");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WEP:
                Serial.print("WEP");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA_PSK:
                Serial.print("WPA");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK:
                Serial.print("WPA2");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK:
                Serial.print("WPA+WPA2");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_ENTERPRISE:
                Serial.print("WPA2-EAP");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA3_PSK:
                Serial.print("WPA3");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_WPA3_PSK:
                Serial.print("WPA2+WPA3");
                break;
            case WIFI_AUTH_WAPI_PSK:
                Serial.print("WAPI");
                break;
            default:
                Serial.print("unknown");
            }
            Serial.println();
            delay(10);
        }
    }
    Serial.println("");

    // Delete the scan result to free memory for code below.
    WiFi.scanDelete();

    // Wait a bit before scanning again.
    delay(5000);
}
```

but this is the output that i get on the serial monitor
[it's not readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6RJY.png)
how can i fix this please ? i don't know what or where is the error

Tried to dispay avaible wifi from esp-wroom-32 on the arduino ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the speed of the serial monitor to the output speed of your program. The program is set to 115,200 baud, the serial monitor to 9600, so it shows garbage because of the speed mismatch. You’ll find the speed option in the Arduino menu near where you select the serial port. Set it to 115,200.

Comment: Thx i din't knew about that